# reading all types of files

Tags: asp.net

I have a .txt file and i open this file, read it and encrypt and decrypt it, it works fine. Now i want to read all types of files like .png, .pdf, .doc etc and do encryption /decryption. file.readtoend() does not work here. How can i do tht?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use a BinaryReader instead of a TextReader. Treat all files as an array of bytes rather than text to do your encryption.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295.aspx

Comment: Hi NerdFury, As u told I used BinaryReader instead of TextReader am able to enryprt but not able to decrypt the data

Comment: @user662417 can you post more code? Make sure you are using a binary reader to read in the encrypted data as well.